# Error in Module Integration Magento 2.1

Tags: magento2, integration

I am having a problem in the magento integration module, whenever I install the module from a company called CMsmart!

The error occurs when I try to create an integration in:

> System-> Integration-> New Integration

The form for completing the new integration does not appear. Only the 'Save' buttons appear.

And if I click this button, the following error appears:

> Warning: Undefined index: all_resources in /mnt/apache2/homolog.brasiltronic.com.br/vendor/magento/module-integration/Controller/Adminhtml/Integration.php on line 129

Is there any way I can fix this error?
[image]

[image]

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Magento\Integration\Controller\Adminhtml;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Magento\Integration\Api\OauthServiceInterface as IntegrationOauthService;

/**
 * Controller for integrations management.
 *
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 */
abstract class Integration extends Action
{
    /**
     * Authorization level of a basic admin session
     *
     * @see _isAllowed()
     */
    const ADMIN_RESOURCE = 'Magento_Integration::integrations';

    /** Param Key for extracting integration id from Request */
    const PARAM_INTEGRATION_ID = 'id';

    /** Reauthorize flag is used to distinguish activation from reauthorization */
    const PARAM_REAUTHORIZE = 'reauthorize';

    const REGISTRY_KEY_CURRENT_INTEGRATION = 'current_integration';

    /** Saved API form data session key */
    const REGISTRY_KEY_CURRENT_RESOURCE = 'current_resource';

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    protected $_registry;

    /** @var \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface */
    protected $_logger;

    /** @var \Magento\Integration\Api\IntegrationServiceInterface */
    protected $_integrationService;

    /** @var \Magento\Integration\Api\OauthServiceInterface */
    protected $_oauthService;

    /** @var \Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data */
    protected $jsonHelper;

    /** @var \Magento\Integration\Helper\Data */
    protected $_integrationData;

    /** @var \Magento\Integration\Model\ResourceModel\Integration\Collection */
    protected $_integrationCollection;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Escaper
     */
    protected $escaper;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
     * @param \Magento\Integration\Api\IntegrationServiceInterface $integrationService
     * @param \Magento\Integration\Api\OauthServiceInterface $oauthService
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data $jsonHelper
     * @param \Magento\Integration\Helper\Data $integrationData
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Escaper $escaper
     * @param \Magento\Integration\Model\ResourceModel\Integration\Collection $integrationCollection
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Integration\Api\IntegrationServiceInterface $integrationService,
        \Magento\Integration\Api\OauthServiceInterface $oauthService,
        \Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data $jsonHelper,
        \Magento\Integration\Helper\Data $integrationData,
        \Magento\Framework\Escaper $escaper,
        \Magento\Integration\Model\ResourceModel\Integration\Collection $integrationCollection
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->_registry = $registry;
        $this->_logger = $logger;
        $this->_integrationService = $integrationService;
        $this->_oauthService = $oauthService;
        $this->jsonHelper = $jsonHelper;
        $this->_integrationData = $integrationData;
        $this->escaper = $escaper;
        $this->_integrationCollection = $integrationCollection;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * Don't actually redirect if we've got AJAX request - return redirect URL instead.
     *
     * @param string $path
     * @param array $arguments
     * @return $this|\Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction
     */
    protected function _redirect($path, $arguments = [])
    {
        if ($this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
            $this->getResponse()->representJson(
                $this->jsonHelper->jsonEncode(['_redirect' => $this->getUrl($path, $arguments)])
            );
            return $this;
        } else {
            return parent::_redirect($path, $arguments);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Restore saved form resources
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function restoreResourceAndSaveToRegistry()
    {
        $restoredFormData = $this->_getSession()->getIntegrationData();
        if ($restoredFormData) {
            $resource = isset($restoredFormData['resource']) ? $restoredFormData['resource'] : [];
            $this->_registry->register(
                self::REGISTRY_KEY_CURRENT_RESOURCE,
                ['all_resources' => $restoredFormData['all_resources'], 'resource' => $resource]
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please add the code of that file?

Comment: I posted as an issue of the publication

Comment: `$restoredFormData` let me know what are you getting in this variable? in `restoreResourceAndSaveToRegistry()` function?

Answer (score 0):

**Always** use arrays like this:

```
(...)
$someArray;

if(isset($someArray["all_resources"])) {
    /* now you can use that `all_resources` value... */
    foreach($someArray["all_resources"] as $resource) {
        $resource...;
    }
}
```

That is your problem in `/mnt/apache2/homolog.brasiltronic.com.br/vendor/magento/module-integration/Controller/Adminhtml/Integration.php on line 129`

You are trying to use array element with key `all_resources` but it's not exist.